# リスト内包表記中のラムダ式が変数をキャプチャする際の挙動

Tags: python, python3

Python3において以下の二つのコードは異なる挙動をします：

```
fs = [lambda x: i*x for i in range(3)]
for i in range(3):
    print(fs[i](3))
```

これは`6 6 6`と出力され、

```
fs2 = []
for i in range(3):
    fs2.append(lambda x: i*x)
for i in range(3):
    print(fs2[i](3))
```

こちらは`0 3 6`と出力されます。
両者は一見同じ挙動をするように思えますが、どうして異なった挙動をするのでしょうか？

Comment: fs と fs2 の lambda function 内の変数 i のスコープがどうなっているのかを考えてみると良いのではないでしょうか。

Comment: これはPython3ですね。Python2では両者とも同じ結果になります。

Comment: 改めて書くと、前者はリスト内包表記のスコープ内のiを参照している。リスト内包表記内のforが実行された後は2になっている‌​。だから2*3で答えはいつも6。ちなみにlambdaは関数なので関数スコープを作るが、iは関数内で定義されていないのですぐ外側のスコープを参照している。結局前者はリスト内包表記スコープのiで、後者ではグローバルスコープのiを参照していることになる。なぜPy‌​thon2だと挙動が違うかというと、Py‌​thon2の内包表記のforは変数が外側‌​のスコープにリークするから。つまり前者をPyt‌​hon2で実行するとiはグローバルのiに‌​なる。Python2の設計時点では実行速度を優先し、言語的な欠陥ではなく仕様だった。フレームの作成は高コストなので。その後Python3ではジェネレータ式と同様、別スコープと修正された。

Comment: フレームの可視化 Python3 https://goo.gl/Cp4s1s  Python2 https://goo.gl/Ag4Fcf

Comment: コメントではなく回答として追加していただけませんか？

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pythonでは、lambdaや関数で外部の値を参照したときに、変数の束縛（バインド）が行われます。

今回起こっていることをおおざっぱに解説すると、 `fs = [lambda x: i*x for i in range(3)]` ではループ毎に実値(0,1,2)を束縛するのではなく、変数(i)そのものを束縛しています。このため、束縛した変数 `i` はループごとに値が変わってしまい、最後の値(i=2)が束縛された状態で終了します。

結果として、後で使う時、 `i*x` の束縛変数`i`は常に2なので、`2*x` => `2*3=6` となります。

---

8/24追記

> この説明だと最初の6 6 6の出力は理解できますが、後者の挙動が理解できません。 – termoshtt

コメントを頂いたので、後者のコードについても説明してみます。

"実値(0,1,2)を束縛するのではなく、変数(i)そのものを束縛しています" と前に説明しましたが、この挙動は後者のコードでも発生しています。

1つ目のforループで変数iを使っていて、2つ目のforループも変数iを使っています。このため、lambdaに束縛されている変数 `i` は、1つ目のforループのiの最終値(i=2)ではなく、2つ目のforループで使われているiの値(0,1,2)を参照します。

このため、  `fs2[i](3)` は `(lambda x: x*i)(3)` ですが、iは0,1,2と変化していきます。結果として、0*3=0, 1*3=3, 2*3=6 という値がプリントされます。

そこで、2つ目のforループの変数名を `i` ではなく `j` にするとどうなるでしょうか。

```
>>> fs2 = []
>>> for i in range(3):
...     fs2.append(lambda x: i*x)
... 
>>> for i in range(3):
...     print(fs2[i](3))
... 
0
3
6
>>> for j in range(3):
...     print(fs2[j](3))
... 
6
6
6
```

i=2で固定されたため、プリントされる値も常に `2*3=6` となりました。

---

詳しい解説については以下のページが参考になります。

- [クロージャのひみつ - atsuoishimoto's diary](http://atsuoishimoto.hatenablog.com/entry/20101006/1286338675)
- [func_closureのひみつ - atsuoishimoto's diary](http://atsuoishimoto.hatenablog.com/entry/20110402/1301709054)

Comment: この説明だと最初の`6 6 6`の出力は理解できますが、後者の挙動が理解できません。

Comment: Python3のリスト内包表記はフレームを作る（スコープが別）になるのと前者ではrangeがジェネレーターであることに関係があると思います。後者では同一フレームで実行されています。ちなみにPython2のリスト内包表記はフレームを作りません。そして前者後者とも同じ結果になります。

Comment: 本文に、疑問への答えを書きました。なお、rangeがジェネレーターであることは関係ないかと思います。Python2での話はそのとおりだと思います。

Comment: rangeの件は関係なかったですね。ところで束縛はバインドですね。

Comment: おっ、束縛=クロージャじゃないですね。ありがとうございます。修正します。